# SQL change first letter to uppercase

Tags: sql, sql-server

How could I change the first letter in this function to uppercase with he remainder staying in lower case?

substring(Column2,charindex('-', Column2)+1,len(Column2)),

Comment: I normally go around this issue by physically storing the value with the first character uppercase and the remaining characters lowercase. From there, it is a lot easier to convert it to all lowercase when needed. :)

Comment: In mysql this works fine SELECT CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT('test', 1)), 
                             LCASE(SUBSTRING('test', 2)));